# Firebird,lock inside trigger

Tags: triggers, deadlock, firebird

Lately I fight with Firebird server with several clients project.I can avoid problems with deadlock in my programming enveroment but I want to do some work in triggers. 
Thanks to advices which I've got from StackOverflow I realy close to my goals but I can not find information about catch deadlock in trigger, wait until it unlock and continue trigger procedure.
Could someone give me link or advice how to face with it?

Siple trigger definition with update or insert inside it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER XYZ FOR TABLE_X ACTIVE AFTER UPDATE POSITION 0 AS
begin
    UPDATE TABLE_X SET FIELD = 1 where contidion
end
```

How to avoid problem when the row I want to change is lock by other process?

Regards,
Artik

Comment: Are you trying to update the same row as the trigger fired for?

Comment: No, I try to modify from ordinary sql command but my application do it to quite often therefore my concern. The deadlock error not happened yet, but I want to be sure - my code is ready for it.

Comment: I am not sure if you can prevent it if you try to update rows other than the specific row the trigger fired for.

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood your question. Yes, I want to update the same row as the trigger fired for.Exactly inversely: I do long update from ordinary sql (task 1) and in the same time trigger fires and wants to do something on dataset locked by task1.

Comment: A lock is different of a deadlock... please edit your question to clarify if you're talking about simple locks or deadlocks?

Answer (score 1):

In your comments you say that you want to update the same row that the trigger fired for, in that case no deadlock can occur, as the current transaction already has the 'lock' on the row, so it is allowed to modify it again. However your approach is wrong. If you want to modify the content of the same row the trigger fired for, you should **not** use an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger, but a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger and use the `NEW` trigger context variables to update one or more columns.

So you trigger should be something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER XYZ FOR TABLE_X ACTIVE BEFORE UPDATE POSITION 0 AS
begin
    IF condition THEN
       NEW.FIELD = 1;
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I understand my english is poor therefore it is difficult explain my problem clearly. If I could, I try it again: I do (from ordinary sql) something on row A in table X. It is long time process - P. In the midle this time something others fired trigger - T. Trigger - T wants to modify row A with is locked by process P. What trigger T can do in this problem situation - it can not modify row A:(?

Comment: If trigger T fired as a result of the modification of row A, and wants to do additional modifications it will not trigger a deadlock, however if trigger T fired for another row (or even table) and then wants to modify row A it could, as far as I know there is nothing you can do to guard against that.

Comment: Thank you. I mean the second scenario:(